# Vim airline/status bar buffers of the same name

Tags: vim, macvim, vim-airline

When I am using vim buffers, I like to look at the status bar instead of using :ls to see which number is associated with the vim buffer.

This becomes problematic when there are multiple files of the same name. Then, the status bar for vim-airline will show:

4: handler.py   10: handler.py  22: handler.py

Is there a way to show some part of the filepath when there are files of the same name?

Surprisingly, I thought this would be a common issue but could not find a solution online.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You are basically using airline to create some kind lookup table. This means you have to not only find your file on the status bar but remember a buffer number and buffer numbers are **lame**.

#### The many ways to switching buffers

- `:sb` and `:b` both can take partial names and globs. e.g. `:sb foo*`
- `:b`/`:sb` use tab completion when used with partial names
- Use `:sb` to switch and split to a buffer you already opened.
- Use `:ls` and `:b` together in a mapping: `nnoremap <leader>b :ls<cr>:b<space>`
- `<c-6>` will go the the previous buffer (can also take an optional buffer number)
- Map `:bnext` and `:bprev` example `[b` and `]b` are [Unimpaired.vim](https://github.com/tpope/vim-unimpaired) mappings
- `set hidden` make switching buffers easier. Don't worry vim will let you know if you have unwritten buffer before exiting
- Use capital letter marks to jump back to buffers where you know you will jump back to.
- Use tags to jump to definitions.
- Possibly use `cscope` along with tags
- Look into fuzzy finder plugsin like [CtrlP](http://kien.github.io/ctrlp.vim/), [Command-T](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3025), and [Unite](https://github.com/Shougo/unite.vim) to switch buffers